# I can't access phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu after successful installation

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, lamp

I have ready LAMP environment on my Amazon EC2 micro instance (Ubuntu).

I have installed phpMyAdmin distribution of Ubuntu, selected Apache 2 as the server, then selected 'yes' for 'db-common-config' option. After it's completed, I'm suppose to access it via `http://server/phpmyadmin`, right? But I can't access it.

Is there any way to verify whether it's been installed properly and is running properly? Or do I have to do anything further?

Answer (score 1):

ok, got it. I didn't add the "Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf" line on apache2 config file. Actually the tutorial I followed, didn't mentioned about that, :p . Never mind.

Comment: Thanks @Rana. That helped. I had to do a restart as well